What should I break: Substitution capability or the Liskov Substitution Principle?
Suppose I have the following class:
template<typename T>
struct A { T* ptr; };

and a bunch of functions which take this class as a parameter, e.g.:
template <typename T>
int one_two_three(A<T> a) { return 123; }

Now, I want to define a class which is:

like A, in the sense that it contains a T* (which one can obtain in an A<T>), and one can pass it somehow to functions taking A; but
is more restricted than A, e.g. lacks public access to its members etc.

Now comes my dilemma. Here are two such A-like classes, named B and C:
template<typename T>
class B {
public:
    using a_type = A<T>;

    B(T* ptr) : a_{ptr} { }
    a_type get() const noexcept { return a_; }
    operator a_type() const noexcept { return get(); }

private:
    a_type a_;
}; 

template<typename T>
class C : public A<T> {
public:
    using a_type = A<T>;

    C(T* ptr) : a_type{ptr} { }
    a_type get() const noexcept { return *this; }
    operator a_type() const noexcept { return get(); }
};

If I use class B, I am unable to substitute A's in calls to one_two_three().
On the other hand, if I use class C - I am able to substitute A's in calls to one_two_three(); but then I am breaking the Liskov substitution principle: C is a subtype of A, but one cannot replace an instance of C wherever an instance of A is used, since C is more restricted.
Can I somehow achieve both the benefits of B and of C in the same class? Or must I choose between these two approaches?
Note:

Assume the slicing of C into an A is safe.
I'd appreciate a C++11-based solution; but if your answer requires a newer C++ standard, that's acceptable too, just please say so.


Motivation: My A is actually a span class, and B or C adds ownership semantics, like a unique_ptr but with a size, and should be usable where I would use a span.

"C is more restricted" In what sense? I don't see that in the code shown. What breaks when you attempt to "replace an instance of C wherever an instance of A is used"?

Re: motivation. Basically, you want f(T*) to accept std::unique_ptr<T>. That sounds to me like a bad idea, and the standard library authors seem to agree, seeing as the library doesn't allow such an implicit conversion. Personally, I'd do B and write one_two_three(b.get()) at the call site.

If C does not change the behavior or impose additional invariants on its base class, then slicing to a A<T> should be okay for pass-by-value.  That being said, I prefer a B style solution in general, and I tend prefer my code to have to do the explicit get() method rather than provide the implicit operator a_type() conversion — because (imo) it makes the code clearer what's going on at the call site using the object.  (But that's just an opinion/style/convention concern.)

@IgorTandetnik: That's a fair opinion. I mean, I'm not deleting the question, but it's something I'll consider. In my motivation it's more like f(span<T>) which I want to accept a unique_span<T>, but same idea. Also, unique_ptr<T> can't inherit T*...

@Eljay: Clarified in the question that slicing is acceptable for pass-by-value. The reason I want to be able to substitute C's for A's is to make it more attractive for certain users to adopt the use of C's. rather than A's. If they have to start writing get-get-get everywhere, I doubt they would be very thrilled with it.

Instead of template<typename T> one_two_three(A<T>), use template<typename Span> one_two_three(Span const& span). The problem with your approach is that your template is too restrictive in what it accepts as parameters. Instead, define an implicit interface which every suitable span type needs to implement. Perhaps also use concepts (not C++11) or similar static assertions to enforce the interface.

@UlrichEckhardt: You're kind of mixing the metaphors here (A/B/C vs span). Regardless.. you often don't control the A class and the functions. Also, a general template is too general. I could use a C++20 concept, though (again, if I controlled everything).

As one_two_three is template, conversion operator cannot be used implicitly, with regular function, it works Demo. And for template, as mentioned in other comments, you might have a more generic template.

@Jarod42: I know this, that's what motivated the question :-(

C also "breaks" some substitution when template is involved. It inherits from A<T> but it is not a A<T>.

@Jarod42: Maybe, but I can pass C's instead of A's to functions which take A's. Or const A& even. And that was what I wanted.
